# Railsでファイル名とクラス名が一致していないクラスを読み込む方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsでファイル名とクラス名が一致していない場合、そのクラスを他のクラスから使うことはできないのでしょうか？

`config/initializers`で`redis.rb`というファイルを設置しています。
このファイルではクラス`DataCache`を下記のように定義している、redisのユーティリティクラスです。

```
class DataCache
  def self.data
    @data ||= Redis.new(host: 'localhost', port: 6379)
  end

  def self.set(key, value)
    data.set(key, value)
  end

  def self.get(key)
    data.get(key)
  end

  def self.get_i(key)
    data.get(key).to_i
  end
end
```

initializersはオートロードパスに含まれていますが、他のクラスからこのDataCacheクラスを利用しようとすると`uninitialized constant 他のクラス名::DataCache`と表示されてしまい利用できません。
ファイル名とクラス名を一致させていない場合のそのクラスの利用方法があれば教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

`initializers`配下においてあるのであればクラス名とファイル名が不一致でも問題ないと思います。（クラス階層とフォルダ階層・ファイル名は同じにした方が当然安全ですが）
手元で適当なrails appを作って試した限りでは、modelからでもcontrollerからでも参照できました。

```
$ cat config/initializers/redis.rb 
class DataCache
end

class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :todo, presence: true
  validates :todo, length: { maximum: 30 }
  has_many :todo_comments

  def self.data
    DataCache.new
  end  
end

Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)
[1] pry(main)> Todo.data
=> #<DataCache:0x007fbebe5f4a18>
```

参照できない可能性として、呼び出している箇所のクラスがmoduleで名前空間が設定されていて、そのmodule配下のクラスとして`DataCache`を探している可能性がありますので、`::DataCache`という形式で参照してみるとどうでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。試しにモデルで私も利用してみた所、問題なくアクセスできました。私が最初にDataCacheクラスを利用していたのはapp/jobsフォルダ内のクラスでこのフォルダだとアクセスできないようです。DataCacheの前に`::`をつけてみましたがダメでした。`application.rb`で`config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/jobs)`としているのでモデルで使えるなら使えても良さそうですが使えません。。

Comment: 呼び出し元である「他のクラス」のソースを追記してくれませんか？